# Viewing results of junit test for gradle?

Tags: junit, gradle, build.gradle

So I currently have the following build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/model'
        }
    }

    test {
        srcDirs = ["tests/model"]
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/mnist-tools.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

that builds successfully when I type "gradle test" into the command line.

However I do the following error when running gradle test:

Creating properties on demand(a.k.a dynamic properties) has been deprecated.

As you can see, my junit tests are all in the folder test/model/ but I was wondering how do I see the results of if my junit tests passed?

You can view my repository here: https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

Comment: If the build succeeds, then the tests pass. An HTML test report is generated in `build/reports/tests`. Why don't you define the test source dir the same way as you do it for the main source dir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chingy,

I had to update a couple of things in your build.gradle:

*source set for tests*
*added Maven repository to get JUnit library*

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/model'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'tests/model'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/mnist-tools.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Now, the results of `$ gradle build`:

```
bender:WalnutiQ demo$ gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test

model.RetinaTest > test_seeBMPImage FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at RetinaTest.java:25

model.MARK_I.SpatialPoolerTest > test_performSpatialPoolingOnRegion FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at SpatialPoolerTest.java:60

model.util.JsonFileInputOutputTest > test_saveRegionObject FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at JsonFileInputOutputTest.java:69

model.util.SynapsePermanencesViewerTest > test_saveRegionToBeOpenedInSynapsePermanencesViewer FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at SynapsePermanencesViewerTest.java:45

49 tests completed, 4 failed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/demo/development/tmp/WalnutiQ/build/reports/tests/index.html
```

I think you can take it from here :o)

PS: I would recommend to refactor your project structure to match Maven/Gradle structure, so you don't have to deal with source sets and it will make your build.gradle cleaner.

```
src/main/java   Production Java source
src/main/resources  Production resources
src/test/java   Test Java source
src/test/resources  Test resources
src/sourceSet/java  Java source for the given source set
src/sourceSet/resources Resources for the given source set
```

Answer (score 4):

When you run `gradle build` or `gradle test`, there is a `build` directory that is created.
This directory is where all the build artifacts are placed.
Inside the `build` directory is a `reports` directory. This directory is where reports are placed.
For example, pmd reports, junit reports, etc.

The JUnit reports are located in the `tests` directory. Open up the `index.html` file in a browser to view the report.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify where the JUnit test results go with the following command within your test block.

```
test {
    reports.junitXml.destination = file('build/test-results/folder')
}
```